# How to use tag helpers when using ViewModel to add multiple models to a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, viewmodel, tag-helpers

I'm building a ASP.NET MVC web application that has several forms in a view. I want the user to be able to fill out each form and capture the data for processing. These forms have a unique model, 3 for this page, that need to be added to the view somehow, so I have tried ViewModel.

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ConModel ConModel { get; set; }
    public CompanyModel CompanyModel { get; set; }
    public ComplaintModel ComplaintModel { get; set; }
    public KnowledgeModel KnowledgeModel { get; set; }
}
```

All the models in the ViewModel look similar:

```
public class ConModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    . . .
}
```

I load ViewModel into my view in the controller:

```
public class FormsController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewModelFraud viewModelFraud = new ViewModelFraud();
        viewModelFraud.ConModel = new ConModel();
        viewModelFraud.CompanyModel = new CompanyModel();
        . . .
        return View(viewModelFraud);
    }
}
```

In my view, I create a tag helper in my form:

```
<form asp-page-handler="Con" method="post">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
         <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
              <input type="text" class="custom-control-input" id="FirstName">
              <label class="custom-control-label" asp-for="FirstName"></label>
         </div>
     </div>
     . . .
```

I'm using `asp-for="FirstName"` tag helper to get a label added to this input element from the model, but I get build errors if I try. The error implies that the tag helper doesn't see the model. Am I loading them incorrectly or at all?

Comment: Did you try `asp-for="ConModel.FirstName"`

Comment: Show the `@model` in *View* file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @pinkfloydx33 and @Farhad Zamani!

Turns out, you need to include the ViewModel into the view like so:

```
  @model WebApp.Models.Con.ViewModel;
```

And `asp-for="ConModel.FirstName"`